# Why am i not allowed to use this string inside the if-bracket?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This maybe a silly question with a simple solution, but i cant figure out why it doesn't let me use the string "datatxt" inside the if-bracket. It says, "The name 'datatxt' does not exist in the current context". Any help is apprechiated.

```
        try
        {      
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Data.txt");
            String datatxt = sr.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error har occured: '{0}'", ex);
        }

        if (UserBox.Text.Equals(user) && PassBox.Text.Equals(data + datatxt)) 
        {
            Main s = new Main(); 
            s.Show();                  
            this.Hide();
```

Comment: Search about variable scope in C# (or NET) Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Variables declared in try block cant be used outside of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `datatxt` is created inside the `try` statement. Try declaring the variable outside the `try` statement and just assigning it inside the `try` statement. e.g.

```
 string datatxt;

    try
    {      
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Data.txt");
        datatxt = sr.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error har occured: '{0}'", ex);
    }

    if (UserBox.Text.Equals(user) && PassBox.Text.Equals(data + datatxt)) 
    {
        Main s = new Main(); 
        ss.Show();                  
        this.Hide(); 
     }
```

Also it would make much more sense if you put the `if` statment inside the `try` so it will not happen if there is an exception.

e.g.

```
string datatxt;

    try
    {      
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Data.txt");
        datatxt = sr.ReadLine();
       if (UserBox.Text.Equals(user) && PassBox.Text.Equals(data + datatxt)) 
        {
          Main s = new Main(); 
          ss.Show();                  
          this.Hide();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error har occured: '{0}'", ex);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks !  That made alot of sense and seems the right way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Variables that are declared in a try block can only be used within the try block. If you need to use a variable set in a try block you must declare it outside the try block, then set the value inside the try block. The placement of your If clause also doesnt make much sense. It would make more sense to move the if block into the try block and leave `dataText` defined inside the try. I have included both ways.

```
String dataText;
try
{      
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Data.txt");
    datatxt = sr.ReadLine();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("An error har occured: '{0}'", ex);
}

if (UserBox.Text.Equals(user) && PassBox.Text.Equals(data + datatxt)) 
{
    Main s = new Main(); 
    s.Show();                  
    this.Hide(); 
}
```

or

```
try
{      
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Data.txt");
    String datatxt = sr.ReadLine();

    if (UserBox.Text.Equals(user) && PassBox.Text.Equals(data + datatxt)) 
    {
        Main s = new Main(); 
        s.Show();                  
        this.Hide(); 
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("An error har occured: '{0}'", ex);
}
```

You can leave the `String dataText;` above the try block if you are going to use the variable again.

Additional Reading:

- [Some MSDN documentation on try catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx)
- [Simple try catch guide](http://www.dotnetperls.com/catch)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `datatxt` is declared inside the `try` block and therefore can only be referenced in that block.

If you want to use it *outside* of the `try` block, then declare it before the `try`.